# Check in function on custom page

Tags: custom-post-types, database, users, front-end

I have a website about places and attractions in my country. Each place/attraction is a different custom post. On this page, i would like to add a button with the value "Check In" and if clicked by a registered user i would like to save a value in db with the: user id, post id and 1 if the button was pressed.

On the user page, i would like to show where he check in and how many times.
I have allready the user page, the places pages, etc. I only need to add this feature.

It's doable? If yes, can someone help me?

LE: I don't expect that someone will just give me the code. Just point me in right direction - how to add for a custom post a custom entry in the db.

Comment: This question is not very specific. Plus, what have you tried? [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Yes, i've read all the google :P - i've searched and reseached but i can find anything concrete. The ideea it's simple - when a registered user clicks a button, i need to save his name and the custom post id in the db. But i've run into a block when i've tried to save anything in db.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this:

`update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'your_meta_data'.$user_id, 'your_value' );` <= this will add for each user 1 field for that post, in db.

All Good :)